# MySQL Trigger Code to enter statement based on another value

Tags: mysql

EDIT **********

I couldn't get the below code to work so I have tried to run it in the diagram tool on Workbench. This is my code

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `MeasureUp_Data`.`bmd_results_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `bmd_l_arm` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO bmd_results VALUES ( new.bmd_l_arm_typ 
CASE new.l_arm_tscore
    WHEN < -2.5 THEN 'osteoporosis'
    WHEN > -2.4 < -1.0 THEN 'osteopenia'
    WHEN > -1.0 THEN 'normal'
    ELSE NULL
    END); 
END
```

Im getting red crosses all though the code. Basically the values will be automatically entered into `data.bmd_l_arm` and I want the field in `data.bmd_results` labelled `bmd_l_arm_typ` to have the text entry based on the numerical result pushed into `l_arm_tscore`

Thanks for you ongoing help!

I am very new to the coding game and have been creating a Db on MySQL to add some value to my company. I have created the DB schema and want to have a field in one of my table insert a value based on a entry which comes into another table. Basically this is for a medical reporting database and I would like the diagnosis to appear in text on in as a field entry.

This is the table which I would like the values to appear, more specially i would like the column (for example) `bmd_sp_typ` to inset a VARCHAR (I will specify the result) based on a numerical result in a different table.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MeasureUp_Data`.`bmd_results` (
  `access_no` INT NOT NULL,
  `bmd_sp_typ` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`access_no`),
  INDEX `pat_id_FK_idx` (`pat_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_site_bmd_site_idx` (`site_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `pat_id_UNIQUE` (`pat_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `site_id_UNIQUE` (`site_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `access_no_UNIQUE` (`access_no` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_demo_results_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pat_id`)
    REFERENCES `MeasureUp_Data`.`patient_demo` (`pat_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_site_bmd_site`
    FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`)
    REFERENCES `MeasureUp_Data`.`site_cont` (`site_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The table where the numerical result will be found is below. Basically is the value for `spine_total_bmd` is `X` then `Y` will be inserted into `bmd_sp_type`, alternatively, if `spine_total_bmd` is `A` then `B` will be inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MeasureUp_Data`.`bmd_spine` (
  `access_no` INT NOT NULL,
  `spine_total_bmd` INT NULL,
  `spine_total_tscore` INT NULL,
  `spine_total_zscore` INT NULL,
  `spine_total_peakref` INT NULL,
  `spine_total_agemat` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`access_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bmd_spine_access`
    FOREIGN KEY (`access_no`)
    REFERENCES `MeasureUp_Data`.`bmd_results` (`access_no`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Any help for this coding noob will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an INSERT trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON bmd_spine
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bmd_results VALUES (
    new.access_no,
    CASE new.spine_total_bmd
      WHEN 1 THEN 'y'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'b'
      ELSE NULL
     END);
END
```

Also, you can just select data from the table and change values on the fly, and do not store duplicated values. Here it is an example -

```
SELECT
  access_no,
  CASE spine_total_bmd
    WHEN 1 THEN 'y'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'b'
    ELSE NULL
  END
FROM
  bmd_spine;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just to clarify if I need 
WHEN 1 THEN 'y' to be between two values can I use the BETWEEN operator or do I put it down as WHEN > -2.5 THEN 'Y' WHEN <-2.5 > -1.5 THEN 'b' etc.

Comment: Have a look at this topic - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case. I this it will shed a light to the question.